# Confusing 'if' statement

Tags: c, if-statement

What is the statement below doing anyway?

It's confusing to me. I am surprised that C allows you to use the conditional operator in an `if` statement. Is there a better way?

I find the conditional operator in an `if` statement too confusing. I could try to use the && and || operators, but I'm afraid I might make a mistake.

How can the statement below be rewritten to be of a simpler form?

```
if ( (offset < 0) ?
         ( input->binData.bounds.lo >= (unsigned long)(-offset) ) :
         ( input->binData.bounds.hi < (unsigned long)(-offset) ) )
```

I found this line of C code in the BitHoist open source package.

Comment: I completely agree with you, this code is unnecessarily obtuse.  Though it does sound like you already have your answer.  I don't know enough C to really help clean this up, but it sounds to me that the entire conditional should probably be extracted into its own function and the "parent" conditional should just check the output of that function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `AND` the ternary condition (`offset < 0`) and its opposite (`offset >= 0`) with each resolution of the ternary operator:

```
if ( ((offset < 0) && ( input->binData.bounds.lo >= (unsigned long)(-offset) )) ||
     ((offset >= 0) && ( input->binData.bounds.hi <  (unsigned long)(-offset) )) ) {
```

Comment: You might also want to make a temporary for (unsigned long)(-offset) and input->binData.bounds to reduce duplication.

Comment: This looks closest to the original code.  so it's safer.  (unsigned long)(-offset) is odd.  I don't understand the code well enough to make big changes.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `input->binData.bounds.lo <= 0 <= input->binData.bounds.hi` and both are `long`, you can take advantage of unsigned arithmetic and comparison to reduce to a single condition.

```
if ((unsigned long)(-offset) - input->binData.bounds.lo <
    input->binData.bounds.hi - input->binData.bounds.lo) { ... }
```

(See [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/) 4-1 Checking Bounds of Integers for a proof of correctness.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a less confusing way to think about it:

```
 overallBool = 0;

if ( (offset < 0) {
       overallBool = input->binData.bounds.lo >= (unsigned long)(-offset);
} else {
       overallBool = input->binData.bounds.hi < (unsigned long)(-offset);
}

if (overallBool) {
    do your thing.
}
```

But obviously it is much bigger in implementation.